# ReplaceAll() replaces wrong substring

Tags: java, string, replace

I have an ArrayList of strings that i need to modify. When i add them to the list they look like this.

```
tick.add("CAST.ST");
tick.add("ELUX-B.ST");
tick.add("EKTA-B.ST");
```

I then have a method to modify the names to remove ".ST" and add ".XML"

```
private static void addFileNames(List<String> ticks, List<File> fileNames)
    {
        List<String> tick = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(int i=0; i<ticks.size(); i++)
            {
            tick.add(ticks.get(i).replaceAll(".ST", ".xml"));

            }
        for(int i=0; i<tick.size(); i++)
        {
            File f = new File("XML/" + tick.get(i));
            fileNames.add(f);

        }
```

This works perfectly for all Strings except "CAST.ST", which gets modified to "C.xml.xml".
I also tried replaceFirst and then it replaces the substring "AST" to "C.xml.ST".

Can someone see what i am doing wrong here?

Comment: did you try `replaceAll("\.ST",".xml")`? You are currently matching any character and then ST, and that is why you get what you get

Comment: Thank you, i had to write  tick.add(ticks.get(i).replaceAll("\\.ST", ".xml"));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape the `.`, `\.`, as a period in regex means *match any character*. In the case of `"CAST.ST"` the posted regex will match `"AST"` and `".ST"`.

Change:

```
tick.add(ticks.get(i).replaceAll(".ST", ".xml"));
```

to:

```
tick.add(ticks.get(i).replaceAll("\\.ST", ".xml"));
```

Comment: Thank you, how come i had to use two backslashes to escape and you only seem to need one? 

 tick.add(ticks.get(i).replaceAll("\\.ST", ".xml"));

Comment: @ZedIsDead, you need to escape the backslash in the string literal as well, hence the two.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is . represents any character in a regex. Escape the dot with "\.ST".

Answer (score 0):

[replaceAll()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) accepts a RegEx expression as the first argument.

Why don't you just use [replace(".ST", ".xml")](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29) since you only want to replace one value from your original value.

No need to use Regex for this answer

Answer (score 0):

Since you need to replace last occurrence to replace file extension, You can use

```
ticks.get(i).replaceAll("\\.st$", ".xml")
```